# jquery find element and add class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add a class to an element inside an li item when a function call is made. I can get the correct value outputted, however finding the child `<i>` is proving difficult. If I could find the correct nested `<i>` and add the class 'show' that would solve it :)

JS code:

```
filterMarkers = function(category) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        // If is same category or category not picked
        if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
            // Show the tick icon
            $(".filter").find("[data-value='" + category + "']").addClass('show');

        }
        // Categories don't match
        else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<ul class="drop-down">
    <li class="filter blue" data-value="" onclick="filterMarkers('');">All <i class="fi-check"></i></li>
    <li class="filter yellow" data-value="test-one" onclick="filterMarkers('test-one');">Sales <i class="fi-check"></i></li>
    <li class="filter red" data-value="test-two" onclick="filterMarkers('test-two');">Incentives <i class="fi-check"></i></li>
    <li class="filter grey" data-value="test-three" onclick="filterMarkers('test-three');">Conferences <i class="fi-check"></i></li>
    <li class="filter orange" data-value="test-four" onclick="filterMarkers('test-four');">Team building <i class="fi-check"></i></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$(".filter[data-value='" + category + "']").addClass('show');` use  this no need to use find since the class filter has the data attr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `filterMarkers` method, you

1. Either want to simply show the category which is passed as argument and hide everything else
2. Or if no argument is passed then hide everything.

Simplify your code to

```
filterMarkers = function(category) {
    $(".filter").removeClass("show"); //remove show class from all
    if( category.length > 0 )
    {
       $(".filter[data-value='" + category + "']").addClass('show');
    }
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) 
    {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        marker.category == category || category.length === 0 ? marker.setVisible( true ) : marker.setVisible( false );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only wish to add the class of show to the li item where the data-value matches the category :)

Comment: @JesseC and not hide the others? Please confirm. In that case, simply remove the first line in the method.

Comment: Yes, when selected add class 'show', remove from all others. The code you suggested isn't adding the class though, the find maybe the issue.

Comment: Thanks @gurvinder372 - it's working, marked as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".filter[data-value='" + category + "']").addClass('show');
```